# New footer clips site name if it is too long

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, footer

The new footer that appears to have been recently rolled out to all sites doesn't contain long site names gracefully. If the site name is too long and gets close to the 'Company' header, the site name is clipped short, even half-way through a character, as shown below:

[image: Computer Science Educators Footer]

[image: Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Footer]

It would be preferable to either overflow on to another line, or work around this, so that the site names aren't clipped in this way.

The sites I've seen affected are:

- Computer Science Educators
- Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair
- Geographic Information Systems
- History of Science and Mathematics
- Programming Puzzles & Code Golf

I'm sure there are several more, but many communities with very long names seem to be affected.

I've reproduced this on Chrome 59 and Firefox 54 at 1920x1080, but I believe all resolutions are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. This has been fixed and it's waiting in repo for build. Should be live in up to couple hours.